# JQuery selective hiding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a menu where each element has its own checkbox. On selecting the sorting button ( for now it is a checkbox here ), the menu is supposed to show only the elements who already have the checkboxes active ( this is done by manually clicking the checkbox of the element and keeping it active)

Here's my HTML code

```
    <input type= "checkbox" class="toggler" id="clicked" onclick="tclick()" >click here to sort 

  <p><input type="checkbox"  id="inactive" onClick="but_clicked()">Hello1</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"  id="inactive" onClick="but_clicked()">Hello2</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"  id="inactive" onClick="but_clicked()">Hello3</p>
```

And here is my Jquery

```
 function but_clicked(){
       // alert("Hello, checkbox clicked");
       if(this.id=="active"){
                this.id="inactive";
        console.log(this.id);}
        else{
            this.id="active";
            console.log(this.id);

        }
    }
    function tclick(){
        //alert("Toggler clicked");
        if(this.id=="clicked"){
            this.id="empty";
            console.log(this.id);        
        }
        else{
            this.id="clicked";
            console.log(this.id);

        }
    }
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggler').change(function(){ 
        if($(this).is('clicked')){
            $('#inactive').hide();
            $('#active').show();
        }
            else{
             $('#active').show();
             $('#inactive').show();
            }
      })
    });
```

But when I am setting the `Click here to sort` checkbox, the others are not being hidden regardless of each of their checkbox status. I feel like it's a very silly  mistake that I am doing, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `id` property **must** be unique in the DOM, so you cannot have multiple elements with id active or inactive.

This is the main problem as `$('#inactive')` will only return the first element it matches (*since it should be unique*).

Furthermore, checkboxes have a `checked` property that signifies if they are checked or not so all your code could just check that instead of altering the `id` all the time.

Last, you should use `label` tags for the text instead of `p` so that clicking on the text will also check/uncheck the checkbox.

(*oh, the `.toggler` checkbox actually filters, and not sorts ,the others*)

So taking all issues into account you could simplify your code to

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').change(function() {
    
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.grouped').parent().hide();
      $('.grouped:checked').parent().show();
    } else {
      $('.grouped').parent().show();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
label{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="toggler">click here to filter</label></p>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="grouped">Hello1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="grouped">Hello2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="grouped">Hello3</label>
```

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Thanks. I tried the `checked` property before but it was not working either. Now I see that I had a slight syntax error. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be way easier with some little tricks.

First thing, do not change IDs at run time, it's a bad practise.
Checkboxes have properties like `checked`, which evaluates to `false` or `true` when tested with `this.checked`.

```
<input type= "checkbox" class="toggler" id="click_to_toggle" >click here to toggle 
<p class="item"><input type="checkbox" >Hello1</p>
<p class="item"><input type="checkbox" >Hello2</p>
<p class="item"><input type="checkbox">Hello3</p>
```

And this is the only JS you need:

```
$('#click_to_toggle').on('change', function(){
    if( this.checked ){
        $('.item').hide();
        $('.item input:checked').each(function(){
            $(this).closest('.item').show();
        });
    } else {
        $('.item').show();
    }
});
```

Working fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/409900/)

Comment: no need to use the `prop`. `this.checked` results in `true`/`false` directly.

Comment: Is it that faster after all?

Comment: Its not an issue of speed (*it would be much faster if your were doing it thousand times per seconds*) but it is cleaner/simpler (*in my opinion*).

Comment: It is working in the fiddle but it isn't working out in my app? Chrome console isn't showing any errors either

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the element itself this `this` in the html, and just use that parameter in your javascript instead of `this`. Also you need to use `.is` with the `:checked` selector instead of just `clicked`. I also change changed `.changed()` to `.clicked()` since they are the same event in this case. You also might want to consider changing the `id` of `inactive`/`active` to be a `class` since all `id`s must be unique.

```js
function but_clicked(e) {
  if (e.id == "active") {
    e.id = "inactive";
    console.log(e.id);
  } else {
    e.id = "active";
    console.log(e.id);

  }
}

function tclick(e) {
  if (e.id == "clicked") {
    e.id = "empty";
    console.log(e.id);
  } else {
    e.id = "clicked";
    console.log(e.id);

  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').click(function() {
    if($('.toggler').is(':checked')) {
      $('#inactive').hide();
      $('#active').show();
    } else {
      $('#active').show();
      $('#inactive').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="toggler" id="clicked" onclick="tclick(this)">click here to sort

<p><input type="checkbox" id="inactive" onClick="but_clicked(this)">Hello1</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="inactive" onClick="but_clicked(this)">Hello2</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="inactive" onClick="but_clicked(this)">Hello3</p>
```

Comment: the main problem is the `$('#inactive')` and `$('#active')` will always return at most 1 element because the `id` **must**  be unique.